# Is there any way to receive Bitcoin Testnet payments?

Tags: testnet, payment

I'm currently working on the implementation of an ERC_20 Token on the Ethereum blockchain. However, I want to allow users to pay with BTC as well. I've already found several services which give me what I need (blockchain.info, [bitcoin-receive-payment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcoin-receive-payments) etc.) However, I cannot find any information on how I can test these (or any) solutions on the Testnet.

There will surely be some gotcha's during development, and I'd rather not mess around with real BTC while I'm at it. Is there any BTC payment service which supports Testnet payments, or will I just have to roll with BTC?

As an extra question (sorry for off-topic) can someone recommend such services for processing Ripple payments?

Thank you in advance. Let me know if I can give any more info that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please do not use blockchain.info if you're gonna test payments.

use block.io instead, it has a full documentation for devs to try it.

you can use Testnet BTCs [HERE](http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/)